# How to interpret nearest neighbors on a square lattice Heisenberg model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm working on a quantum computing problem and I can't wrap my head around what it meant by nearest neighbor pairs on a 4-site (4-qubit) square lattice. For example here:

[image]

If, for example, the four-site lattice is ordered left-to-right, top-to-bottom, then the pairs would be:

- [1, 2]
- [3, 4]

Or they would include the vertical pairs too, like so?

- [1, 2]
- [3, 4]
- [2, 3]
- [1, 4]

Comment: It is not clear what is the meaning of your [i,j] pairs.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem too. But all papers I read refer to "nearest neighbor pairs" without defining them as it there was a generally understood definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Nearest neighbour*  are pairs separated by one link.  *Next nearest neighbour* pairs are those  across the diagonal of the square. You have to traverse two links of the square lattice  to get from one to another.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! So basically this means [1, 2][3, 4][2, 3][1, 4] on a 4-site lattice, correct?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: I would say nn are *pairs of sites at the minimum distance*. The presence of a link is somewhat ambiguous.: in the case of next-nearest neighbor interactions on a square lattice of lattice constant $a$, also pairs separated by $a \sqrt{2}$ are joined by one link.

Comment: @Giorgio.  Square lattice has sides not diagonals in my Lattice World, but ....  I think I learned this stuff from you.